# BouncyCastle JsseProvider configure named groups without modifying jdk.tls.namedGroups

Tags: java, ssl, bouncycastle

Is it possible to configure the BouncyCastleJsseProvider to use a specific elliptic curve without modifying the system property `jdk.tls.namedGroups` in Java 17?

I need an `SSLContext` supporting only a specific curve. Ideally this should be achievable without tinkering with the system property to not interfere with other TLS connections.

Java 20 [adds support for this configuration](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8291950) via the `SSLParameters` but updating to Java 20 is not a real option for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BCJSSE has not yet added the new `SSLParameters` methods; I will look at adding them now. I would expect similar methods to then also be backwardly available (i.e. in all supported JDK versions) via our extension API.

Also, just to clarify, BCJSSE supports the jdk.tls.namedGroups property always (no JDK or BCJSSE version dependency).

In the meantime it should be possible to subclass `JcaTlsCrypto` and override `hasNamedGroup()`. To enable this in your provider instance, subclass also `JcaTlsCryptoProvider` and override `create(SecureRandom, SecureRandom)` to create an instance of your JcaTlsCrypto subclass.

Finally, either pass your JcaTlsCryptoProvider to `BouncyCastleJsseProvider(boolean, JcaTlsCryptoProvider)` constructor or if you are using java.security configuration use the config string to name your JcaTlsCryptoProvider subclass.

UPDATE:

We just released 1.74 which contains support for the new `SSLParameters` properties. In earlier Java versions you would need to access the functionality though our extension API. e.g. cast `SSLSocket` to `org.bouncycastle.jsse.BCSSLSocket` and call `BCSSLSocket#setParameters(BCSSLParameters)` after using `BCSSLParameters#setNamedGroups`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! 
Is my assumption correct, that the integer value of the named group can be obtained from: https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/tlsdocs1.8on/constant-values.html#org.bouncycastle.tls.NamedGroup.brainpoolP512r1 ? E.g. 28 for brainpoolP512r1 ? Thanks alot!

Comment: What I forgot to mention, brainpoolP512r1 was added to jdk.disabled.namedCurves in Java 16 (https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8251547)

Comment: Yes, NamedGroup has the appropriate constants. jdk.disabled.namedCurves is currently ignored by BCJSSE.

Comment: The solution you proposed works fine if my subclassed version of `JcaTlsCrypto` supports secp256r1, secp521r1 (i == 23 || i == 25). 
I can then test the server via:
`openssl s_client -debug -tls1_2 -curves secp256r1 -cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 localhost:9000`.
Oddly enough when changing it to support brainpoolP256r1 or brainpoolP512r1 (i==26 || i ==28). It is not possible to connect via `openssl s_client -debug -tls1_2 -curves brainpoolP256r1 -cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 localhost:9000`. Do you have additional pointers? Thanks alot!

Comment: You would still need to enable the brainpool curves using jdk.tls.namedGroups system property since they are not in our default list.

Comment: @tobhai See updated answer regarding our 1.74 release.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
Is it still necessary to enable brainpoolP256r1 via the jdk.tls.namedGroups property?

Comment: Use of SSLParameters.namedGroups overrides/replaces any jdk.tls.namedGroups setting, so the latter should be unnecessary.